# SGE error can't open output file

Tags: sungridengine

I'm trying to run `PsN` with `run_on_sge` but keep getting this error when I submit multiple runs simultaneously. I'm also getting "error: can't chdir to directory".

I suspect the `PsN` scripts may not be creating the run directories before submitting the job but am not certain. I'm also a little unsure of how to test this.

The nodes have access to the `NFS` mounted directories in question and the permissions look fine. Any pointers appreciated!!

Comment: What is psn and what is run_on_sge? I'm used to running jobs with qrsh and qsub.

Comment: PsN: Perl-Speaks-NONMEM. It creates a qsub script and submits the job by calling qsub.

Answer (score 1):

Note to self: don't mess up the UID's when creating user accounts on the compute nodes.

UID's did not match between (3) compute nodes and the head node... which resulted in 'intermitted' failures with the error mentioned. Whenever a job was submitted to a UID mismatched node the job failed with what now seems to be a pretty obvious error message.